# How can I setup a custom run setup for path(for code runner extension)?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

So when I run [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) (using java) it asks for **javac**

so I have to set up a path, but on the computer that I'm using doesn't allow permanent path so, I've been using:

> set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin   ***for cmd***

or

> $env:Path = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin"; ***for powershell***

I'm using the VS Code **run in terminal** so it gives me the .class (yes I know that if I run it in F5 it has no problems but I don't like the text mess on the terminal XD)

So the question is how can I make a custom command so it sets up the path (be it at startup or every time)

Or, Do I have to modify the default settings? (if so where is the file location)

Answer (score 0):

To set the default path on Windows, go to Control Panel, System, Advanced System Settings, Environment Variables.

Comment: I already know this. But in the computer I'm talking about i cant do this cause it requires admin privileges. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

For cmd:
1.open a cmd and run the commands:
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun ^ /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%"USERPROFILE"%\init.cmd" /f
2.create a file in your USERPROFILE(likes:C:\Users\UserName) folder named "init.cmd" and then you can set the commands which you want to run automatically when the Command Prompt is launched.

Comment: I guess not a bad idea, but what I want is for the [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) to run a custom run, Dou idk if i can run this on the computer I'm talking about

Comment: I got it, you can try this:
in the settings.json type in "code-runner" and then select the "code-runner.executorMap",it will automatically give you a lot of settings for every languages, then you can set the java setting from this:

"java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt path",

to this:

"java": "cd $dir && D:/workSoft/JDK8/bin/javac $fileName && D:/workSoft/JDK8/bin/java $fileNameWithoutExt path",

Comment: So i managed to modify the settings.json, dou i couldn't manage to make your solution (i think its cause the folder has a space) i did end up doing what i wanted **"java": "$env:Path = \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_241\\bin\"; cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt;",** :)